# Refactor 5 in a Row Win Logic (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop

I'm having trouble translating my win logic into something more concise. I've tried by using a for loop to iterate over the board. My board is 9x9 built using uls and lis:

```
   <ul>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
    <li class="board open"></li>
  </ul>
```

There's also an invisible grid made with uls and lis, which is how player moves are shown. The background image of the li changes to that player's stone:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
    <li class="grid open"></li>
  </ul>
```

My win logic checks rows, columns and diagonals for 5 in a row, but I've just found every possible win case and manually written them in. Here's an example of the row win function:

```
    return  checkSquares([squares[0],squares[1],squares[2],squares[3],squares[4]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[1],squares[2],squares[3],squares[4],squares[5]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[2],squares[3],squares[4],squares[5],squares[6]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[3],squares[4],squares[5],squares[6],squares[7]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[4],squares[5],squares[6],squares[7],squares[8]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[9],squares[10],squares[11],squares[12],squares[13]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[10],squares[11],squares[12],squares[13],squares[14]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[11],squares[12],squares[13],squares[14],squares[15]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[12],squares[13],squares[14],squares[15],squares[16]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[13],squares[14],squares[15],squares[16],squares[17]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[18],squares[19],squares[20],squares[14],squares[22]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[19],squares[20],squares[21],squares[22],squares[23]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[21],squares[22],squares[23],squares[24],squares[25]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[22],squares[23],squares[24],squares[25],squares[26]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[27],squares[28],squares[29],squares[30],squares[31]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[28],squares[29],squares[30],squares[31],squares[32]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[29],squares[30],squares[31],squares[32],squares[33]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[30],squares[31],squares[32],squares[33],squares[34]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[31],squares[32],squares[33],squares[34],squares[35]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[36],squares[37],squares[38],squares[39],squares[40]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[37],squares[38],squares[39],squares[40],squares[41]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[38],squares[39],squares[40],squares[41],squares[42]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[39],squares[40],squares[41],squares[42],squares[43]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[40],squares[41],squares[42],squares[43],squares[44]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[45],squares[46],squares[47],squares[48],squares[49]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[46],squares[47],squares[48],squares[49],squares[50]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[47],squares[48],squares[49],squares[50],squares[51]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[48],squares[49],squares[50],squares[51],squares[52]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[49],squares[50],squares[51],squares[52],squares[53]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[54],squares[55],squares[56],squares[57],squares[58]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[55],squares[56],squares[57],squares[58],squares[59]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[56],squares[57],squares[58],squares[59],squares[60]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[57],squares[58],squares[59],squares[60],squares[61]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[58],squares[59],squares[60],squares[61],squares[62]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[63],squares[64],squares[65],squares[66],squares[67]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[64],squares[65],squares[66],squares[67],squares[68]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[65],squares[66],squares[67],squares[68],squares[69]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[66],squares[67],squares[68],squares[69],squares[70]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[67],squares[68],squares[69],squares[70],squares[71]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[72],squares[73],squares[74],squares[75],squares[76]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[73],squares[74],squares[75],squares[76],squares[77]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[74],squares[75],squares[76],squares[77],squares[78]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[75],squares[76],squares[77],squares[78],squares[79]]) ||
      checkSquares([squares[76],squares[77],squares[78],squares[79],squares[80]]);
```

As you can see, it's insanely long. I've tried doing a nested for loop that is supposed to compare 5 squares each time, but I'm getting an infinite loop:

```
    for(var a = 0; a < squares.length; a++){
     for(var b = 1; b < squares.length; b++){
       for(var c = 2; c < squares.length; c++){
        for(var d = 3; d < squares.length; d++){
          for(var e= 4; e < squares.length; e++){
            if((a + b + c+ d+ e) % 5 == 0){ 
           return checkSquares([squares[a],squares[b],squares[c],squares[d],squares[e]]);
          }
         } 
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

I may be trying to achieve this refactor in a very complicated way. So, I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!!

Comment: It's not an _infinite_ loop, just a really big loop, `3074591520` iterations!

Comment: Changing `squares` into a multidimensional array (ie an array of column or row arrays) will make your life a lot easier imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check every square against every other square; `81 * 80 * 78 * 77 * 76` checks (`3074591520`) is way too large. Even without a sophisticated algorithm, you can get really far just reducing your problem space:

1. Check rows (9 * (9 - 4) = 45 checks)
2. Check columns (same, 45 checks)
3. Check `/` diagonals for wins (too lazy to do the math, but same sort of order of magnitude)
4. Check `\` diagonals

So without too much work you can change this to 100's of checks, which will be way faster, and your loops will just be looping through rows, columns, and diagonal indexes:

```
// Rows
for (var row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
    var i = row * 9 + col;
    checkSquares([
      squares[i  ], 
      squares[i+1],
      squares[i+2],
      squares[i+3],
      squares[i+4]
    ]);
  }
}

// Cols
for (var col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
  for (var row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    checkSquares([
      squares[(row    ) * 9 + col], 
      squares[(row + 1) * 9 + col],
      squares[(row + 2) * 9 + col],
      squares[(row + 3) * 9 + col],
      squares[(row + 4) * 9 + col]
    ]);
  }
}

// etc
```

Comment: Ahhhh...that makes sense. I've been thinking solely in terms of individual squares. I'll try this way. Much more manageable. Thank you! I really appreciate your response.